# How Do We Distinguish User Scrolls from scrollToPosition() Scrolls in RecyclerView.OnScrollListener?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my `onScrolled()` method of a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`, I need to be able to distinguish between two different sources of scroll events:

- The user scrolling the `RecyclerView` using touch events
- Code scrolling the `RecyclerView` using `scrollToPosition()`

There is no parameter to `onScrolled()` that would appear to cover this. Is there a recipe for making this distinction?

FWIW, my scenario: I have two `RecyclerView` widgets. One is the master, and shows a traditional vertical list. The other is serving as a `ViewPager` replacement, to allow for swiping through details of the same items that are in the vertical list. In a large-screen environment, both `RecyclerView` widgets will be visible at once (master-detail pattern), and I need to keep them synchronized. If the user swipes the pager `RecyclerView`, I need to change an indicator on the list `RecyclerView` rows to match. If the user taps on a row in the list `RecyclerView`, I need to update the current page in the pager `RecyclerView`. To listen for swipe events on the pager, I am using `OnScrollListener`, but that also is getting triggered when *I* scroll the pager in response to list row clicks.

Comment: The question is very clear. However, it would be great if you could attach any UI sample along with it. Thanks.

Comment: and also the xml layout would be great ..

Comment: Hack solution:  in scrollToPosition, set a flag.  In onScrolled, when you reach the position you wanted, clear the flag.  Then you can check if you're scrolling from scrollToPosition by checking the flag.  You could also use onScrollStateChanged to clear the flag (clear it every idle).

Comment: @GabeSechan: Yeah, I tried a flag, and it was not proving to be reliable. I didn't consider `onScrollStateChanged()`, though, so that's worth looking into. Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you won't get around a "hack" like others suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabe Sechan's suggestion of using the scroll-state change is a good one.

Unfortunately, there is no listener for the scroll state — it requires that you subclass `RecyclerView`. So, I whipped up a `RecyclerViewEx` to add a listener API for that event:

```
public class RecyclerViewEx extends RecyclerView {
  interface OnScrollStateChangedListener {
    void onScrollStateChanged(int state);
  }

  final private ArrayList<OnScrollStateChangedListener> listeners=new ArrayList<>();

  public RecyclerViewEx(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public RecyclerViewEx(Context context, @Nullable
    AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public RecyclerViewEx(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs,
                        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public void addOnScrollStateChangedListener(OnScrollStateChangedListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }

  public void removeOnScrollStateChangedListener(OnScrollStateChangedListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
  }

  @Override
  public void onScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(state);

    for (OnScrollStateChangedListener listener : listeners) {
      listener.onScrollStateChanged(state);
    }
  }
}
```

`scrollToPosition()` does not trigger a scroll-state change, whereas user swipes do. So, I can distinguish between the two scenarios that way.

```
rve.addOnScrollStateChangedListener(
  scrollState -> {
    if (scrollState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
      // do something cool, now that the user swipe is complete
    }
  });
```

Given this, I do not need a flag or any other state, which helps keep the logic simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will not work if you are using `smoothScrollBy()` or `smoothScrollToPosition()`. The only way to tell if the scroll was from user is to set a flag when the user is **dragging**, when this happen the `RecyclerView` state would be changed to `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`. Then, when the state changed to `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, you need to clear the flag.

```kotlin
var scrolledByUser = false

rv.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrollStateChanged(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        newState: Int
    ) {
        when (newState) {
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                scrolledByUser = true
            }
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                if (scrolledByUser) {
                    // fromUser
                } else {
                    // from smoothScroll
                }
                scrolledByUser = false
            }
        }
    }
})
```